# Kivy layout not working when using nested Widget

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to nest a Widget with it's own layout:

```
<InnerPanel>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            text: 'Order # 141'
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
        Label:
            text: 'Good id: 14'
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
        Label:
            text: 'Good type: A'
            size_hint: 1, 0.3
<MainPanel>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Image:
            source: 'crate_target.png'
            size: self.texture_size
        InnerPanel:
```

Having this the content of the InnerPanel is sticked to the bottom-left corner of the application window. However if to remove InnerPanel and place it's content directly to MainPanel everything works correctly:

```
<MainPanel>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Image:
            source: 'crate_target.png'
            size: self.texture_size
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                text: 'Order # 141'
                size_hint: 1, 0.3
            Label:
                text: 'Good id: 14'
                size_hint: 1, 0.3
            Label:
                text: 'Good type: A'
                size_hint: 1, 0.3
```